# How to properly propagate error messages using Python

Tags: python, exception, error-handling

I am kinda new to proper Python error handling and I struggle finding the beast way how to handle errors in the chain of several methods.

I have 3 methods - `a`, `b`, `c`. `a` is calling `b` and `b` is calling `c`. How to propagate the error from the method `c` back to the method `a` so I can e.g. store somewhere it or return during API response?

Example code:

```py
def c(x, y):
  try:
    return int(x), int(y)
  except Exception:
    print("x or y is probably not a number")

def b(x, y):
  try:
    x, y = c(x, y)
    return x + y
  except Exception:
    print("issue during sum of x and y")

def a(x, y):
  try:
    return b(x, y)
  except Exception:
    print("some unknown error occured")

 
result = a(4, 5)
result = a('test', 10)
```

The code above prints some errors under some conditions. It's pretty clear that you can see those errors in the console, but how to work with those 'error' messages later? For example I would like to return them and store if method `a` is called from another module. Right now the `result` has value of `None`, in case of an error occurency.

In other words, I would like to "somehow" jump from method `c` directly back into method `a` and display the response.

Is the proper way to return the error message itself like this?

```py
def c(x, y):
  try:
    return int(x), int(y)
  except Exception:
    return "x or y is probably not a number"
```

Comment: The `traceback` module has functions for getting info about the current exception, https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html

Comment: @Filip_Niko Thank to the comment of anton I have updated the answer using traceback. Now a decorator returns the traceback as a string if the function fails

Answer (score 3):

**error propagation**

If you want to propagate the exception you can use use from clause

all the information ca be check here https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-raise-stmt

```py
def c(x, y):
    try:
        return int(x), int(y)
    except Exception as e:   
        msg = "x or y is probably not a number"
        raise Exception(msg) from e   

def b(x, y):
    try:
        x, y = c(x, y)
        return x + y 
    except Exception as e:
        msg = "issue during sum of x and y"
        raise Exception(msg) from e   

def a(x, y):
    try:
        return b(x, y)
    except Exception as e:
        msg = "some unknown error occured"
        raise Exception(msg) from e    

result = a('test', 10)
```

That way you have tracked all way back all errors and their origins

this is the output:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ho5K.png

**supresion of traceback**

in case you want to supress all the traceback of the error  you need to use
 `from None`

```py
def a(x, y):
    try:
        return b(x, y)
    except Exception as e:
        msg = "some unknown error occured"
        raise Exception(msg) from None
```

Now running the code will  supress all previos errors, this is the output:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/loFis.png

**Recovering the error as a string**

The best way to capture the error I found so far and thanks to the comments of @anton who suggested using traceback is using a decorator

```py
from functools import wraps, partial
import traceback  
import sys


def error_handler(func=None, *, raise_error=False):
    if not func:
        return partial(error_handler, raise_error=raise_error)
    
    @wraps(func)
    def func_exectutor(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            out = func(*args, **kwargs)
            exception = False
        except Exception as error:
            exception = True
            string = ''.join(traceback.format_exception(None, error, error.__traceback__))
            out = string, error
        finally:
            if not exception:
                return out
            else:
                if raise_error:
                    raise out[1]
                else:
                    return out[0]
    return func_exectutor
```

after decorating the function:

```py
@error_handler(raise_error=False)
def a(x, y):
    try:
        return b(x, y)
    except Exception as e:
        msg = "some unknown error occured"
        raise Exception(msg) from e
```

The output of the function if fails, is a string that contains the traceback of all the possible errors that occurred. If not the output is the expected one

```
a(4, 10)
>>> 14

a('test', 10)
>>> 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/tmp/ipykernel_60630/2959315277.py", line 3, in c\n    return int(x), int(y)\nValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: \'test\'\n\nThe above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:\n\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/tmp/ipykernel_60630/2959315277.py", line 10, in b\n    x, y = c(x, y)\n  File "/tmp/ipykernel_60630/2959315277.py", line 6, in c\n    raise Exception(msg) from e\nException: x or y is probably not a number\n\nThe above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:\n\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/tmp/ipykernel_60630/2959315277.py", line 19, in a\n    return b(x, y)\n  File "/tmp/ipykernel_60630/2959315277.py", line 14, in b\n    raise Exception(msg) from e\nException: issue during sum of x and y\n\nThe above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:\n\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/tmp/ipykernel_60630/879165569.py", line 13, in func_exectutor\n    out = func(*args, **kwargs)\n  File "/tmp/ipykernel_60630/2959315277.py", line 22, in a\n    raise Exception(msg) from e\nException: some unknown error occured\n'
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It works unless I need to process the error message later (e.g. ship it as API response), right? I was aware of the raise, but as far as I can Google it only seemed like the core will break and you can see the errors in the console. Which is not my case. 
Let me know if this is not clear and I need to improve my question.
Thanks

Comment: Ohh I totally miss the concept of the question. Sorry, let me think of something

Comment: Have you consider ussing a logging to do what you want?

Comment: I have added an extra part explaining how to recover all the errors and the traceback as a string, I think those object can be then use ship then as an object if it is not clear let me know

Comment: The `traceback` module has functions for getting info about the current exception, https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html

Comment: @antont Thank for the comment I have updated the answer using traceback. Now a decorator returns the traceback as a string if the function fails

Comment: Guys, thanks! This looks promising. I am gonna try to implement this into my codebase.
PS: Logging is not an option, since I need to return the error message as a part of the API request (all events are still logged).

Comment: Yep @FilipNiko we do the same, throw Python exceptions in internal app logic, and then return HTTP errors with informative messages from the API code. I think the traceback module could be used simply inside a catch in the api code, to read exception details, but we didn't do that in our app yet. Maybe the decorator from Lucas is nice, I didn't fully grasp it yet.

Comment: @antont, The use of the decorator allows you to avoid using try and except clauses in every function you may think will fail and handle the errors since the decorator handle exceptions by itself.  Once you put the decorator on top of any function (containing or not try except clauses), If the function fails it returns the error as a string or raise this error (raise_error parameter control the different cases). If the function works works correctly it  returns the normal output.

Comment: Right, thanks for info @LucasM.Uriarte . We want to return appropriate HTTP error codes, not just strings with the message, so handle exceptions individually anyway. But maybe we could extend such a decorator to have suitable exception type -> http error code mapping.

Comment: @antont, I think I cannot help much more regarding http erros, and I know very litle about APIs actually I have never used one (I'm a chemist not an IT guy). but I think you can still keep working on the last ```else``` statement at that point ``` out ``` is a tuple of lenght 2. The first element is the error as a string the second is the error itself, I think you can keep working with that error, or return instead of the string the error itself  change```return out[1]``` or ```return out``` to have both elements. If you have more questions regarding the decorator let me know