# Exiting a function

Tags: python, mysql, database, function

hello i have 2 functions
the first one looks like this

```
def insert_link_into_bd (category,title,link,author,author_link,finally_text,date):
    cursor = db.cursor(buffered=True)
    try:
        syntext = """Insert into links (Category,Title,Article_link,Author,Author_link,Text, DATE) values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s);"""
        value = ((category),(title),(link),(author),(author_link),(finally_text),(date))
        cursor.execute(syntext,value)
        db.commit()
    except ...
```

In the second function I call the first one

```
def second():
    //actions
    insert_link_into_bd(category, title, link, author, author_link, finally_text, date)
```

I'm interested in how you can exit the second function if an error pops up in the first

I tried like this, but my code is connected to the telegram bot and when I execute a cron-jobs, my code completely stops executing due to exit(), but I need only this file to stop executing (I have several such files in cron jobs)

```
def insert_link_into_bd (category,title,link,author,author_link,finally_text,date):
    cursor = db.cursor(buffered=True)
    try:
        syntext = """Insert into links (Category,Title,Article_link,Author,Author_link,Text, DATE) values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s);"""
        value = ((category),(title),(link),(author),(author_link),(finally_text),(date))
        cursor.execute(syntext,value)
        db.commit()
    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
            print(err.sqlstate)
            if err.sqlstate=='23000':
                exit()
```

Comment: This comes down to error raising (using `raise`) and propagation. There's a good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73719768/2221001) on how to do this in python.

Comment: Your bracketing of values in `value` does look a bit excessive. It just has to be a tuple. You also don't need the `;` or the triple quotes unless you're doing a multi-line string.

Comment: ```
  except mysql.connector.Error as err:
            msg='23000'
            raise mysql.connector.Error(msg) from err
```
like this?

Comment: If you're just going to raise the same exception, just leave out the `try/except` and the exception will be propagated to the caller automatically.

Comment: @Barmar I need the function to break only on error 23000, and for example, on 22007 it continues to work, so I can't get rid of try except

Comment: OK, then `if err.sqlstate == '23000': raise err` to re-reaise the same exception.